# Flutter объединить два аудио файла (наложить на друг друга)

Tags: flutter, dart

Кода нет , хотел узнать куда вообще копать , мне нужно объединить два файла, на одном голос на другом музыка.

Comment: Это задача явно не для Flutter, можно сделать нативно (Kotlin, Swift) `PlatformChannel`. Но вообще это задача больше для Backend.

Comment: Да вроде как можно с помощью FFmpeg plugin for Flutter )) не проверял пока

Comment: Не хотелось бы через Backend

Comment: Ну думайте сами, я предложил свои варианты, возможны уже есть плагины которые так умеют.